# Adding a URL parameter to Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a well behaving API that I'm going against but in one case there is a twist that I'm hoping Ember can accommodate. Specifically when I call DELETE on an endpoint, the default behaviour is to *not* truly delete it but rather to set the workflow status to "marked_for_deletion" which makes it invisible to most apps. There are, however, situations where I want to ACTUALLY delete the record and doing this is simply a matter of including a URL parameter of `immediate=true`. If I were doing this with AJAX it would be as simple as can be but I'm wondering what the "right" way of doing this is with Ember-Data.

Anyone have a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must use query parameter. It's not related with ember-data check [this guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/).

Be careful because API will be changed